# Visual Studio C# datagridview to database

Tags: c#, database, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to save data from ***datagridview to database***. I keep on getting a

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

---

```
try 
{           
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
    {            
        using ( conn = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_Students_Marks VALUES(@Student, @T1, @T2, @T3, @T4)", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Student", (row.Cells["Student Number"].Value).ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T1", row.Cells["Test 1"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T2", row.Cells["Test 2"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T3", row.Cells["Test 3"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T4", row.Cells["Test 4"].Value);
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
```

Comment: Can you provide line number where you got this error?

Comment: Line 9 in the above code.

Comment: use index number instead of index name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your row value is empty.

Try to replace your line 9 with this code:

```
            var studentNumber = row.Cells["Student Number"].Value
            if (studentNumber == null || studentNumber is DBNull)
              continue;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Student", studentNumber.ToString());
```

Comment: @ArtemNow it giving me this error: ***The parameterized query '(@Student nvarchar(4000),@T1 nvarchar(4000),@T2 nvarchar(4000),@' expects the parameter '@T1', which was not supplied.***

Comment: Line number with error again please (after your inserted my code).

Answer (score 1):

hmmm try this codes

```
try 
{           
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
{            
    using ( conn = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(constring))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_Students_Marks VALUES(@Student, @T1, @T2, @T3, @T4)";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Student", (row.Cells["Student Number"].Value).ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T1", row.Cells["Test 1"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T2", row.Cells["Test 2"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T3", row.Cells["Test 3"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T4", row.Cells["Test 4"].Value);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
```

i hope it helps you

Comment: it still giving me the same exception

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the empty row from the bottom of your `DataGridView` first. this is why you can not insert last row. like this (Set `AllowUserToAddRows` to `False` in the `DataGridView Properties` or Add `dataGridView2.AllowUserToAddRows = false;` in your filling `DataGridView` method):

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
dataGridView2.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

Then rest of your code to `INSERT`.